# SharePoint designer workflow get suspended when item created in document library using Send Email action

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

I have created a simple workflow with Send Email action in SharePoint 2013 document library, the email will send when a new item added to document library.

When an item created in document library, the workflow get suspending with the below error.

> RequestorId: 26df5cee-92d9-9ac0-0000-000000000000. Details: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow
>   instance. Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 500
>   {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["77"],"SPRequestGuid":["26df5cee-92d9-9ac0-aacf-b0c020be4369"],"request-id":["26df5cee-92d9-9ac0-aacf-b0c020be4369"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4675"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1;
>   RequireReadOnly"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],"Date":["Wed,
>   30 Jan 2019 04:49:08
>   GMT"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS/8.5"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]}
>   at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Emails triggering fine in other sites, the workflows get suspending with particular to this site.

Kindly provide suggestions to get resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is necessary to increase the user's rights to the list of workflow history to the level of "Collaboration" permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem few weeks ago in SPO, probably the same cause. Follow instructions:

1. Check under which **Account is running this workflow** - if its some Service Account it has not email address probably
2. Go to All Users table - its on Root Site Collection: **https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/zvi/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0** and find your Service Account
3. There is not any email address, so the **workflow has problem with sending email when sender has not email address**. You can **set email address here** or you can set it in UPS or AD *(the email can't existed in real you only need some email address from which will be send this email)*

Added another solutions:

1. Check if your Log in History action has not exceeded limit of 255
   characters.
2. Check if you have proper permissions to History List and Workflow list on this site.
3. Check if in library where is workflow in not set "Require documents to be checked out, before they can be edited
4. Do full User profile Synchonization
5. Try this [POST](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spses/2015/06/18/sharepoint-2013-sharepoint-designer-workflow-in-suspended-or-canceled-state/)

If this is ok, there can be problem with some permissions, have you published this workflow with the same account? It's 100% same?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I am triggering the workflow with my user account and sending the email to my account only. The workflows are intermittently suspending with HTTP 500 error. Could you please suggest what's causing the problem

Comment: Added some more solutions, try them

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use the Alert options in this site?
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-alert-to-get-notified-when-a-file-or-folder-changes-in-sharepoint-e5a79e7b-a146-46da-a9ef-d65409ba8918

Maybe you don't need a workflow because the alert functionality is enough.

If you cannot set up Alerts then it's possible that this site isn't configured to send emails.

Comment: Alerts are working fine in SharePoint list & document libraries, but we have an requirement to send an email through workflow when an item created in list/library. But the workflow gets suspending with HTTP 500 error.

Comment: can anyone suggest on the issue to get it the issue resolved.

Comment: Can use share more logs from ULS? I think you can filter by the Correlation ID with the value of the **"SPRequestGuid"**:["26df5cee-92d9-9ac0-aacf-b0c020be4369"] from your error message. Ofc, when you start a new workflow to create new logs this SPRequestGuid will change and you need to use the new value when filtering the ULS logs.

Comment: UpdatedConcurrencyException: The object UserProfileImportJob Name=User Profile Service Application_ProfileImportJob was updated by another user.  Determine if these changes will conflict, resolve any differences, and reapply the second change.  This error may also indicate a programming error caused by obtaining two copies of the same object in a single thread. Previous update information: User:[UserAccount]Process:OWSTIMER (17924) MachineTime:December 29, 2017 01:04:36.0000  Current update information: User:[UserAccount] Process:OWSTIMER (10128) Machine:[] Time:February 11, 2019 10:58:40.1232

Comment: Getting the ULS logs as mentioned above. Could you please help me on to get it resolve.And the workflow get suspending particular to this site collection and intermittently it's getting suspending. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding an extra "Pause for Duration" step as the first step of the Workflow. Try 1, 5 or 10 minutes. When you upload the file is blocked for a sort amount of time, your workflow has to wait a little.

Comment: Even i am getting the same error when i create a new item in list also, the workflow gets suspending.

Comment: Is there anything else in your workflow or just the send email step? Does it work if you manually start the WF and not automatically? Are testing with only one user account or multiple? That log was generated in December, do you have newer?

Comment: The workflow having only send an Email action, and it's getting suspending with other than my user account also and the workflow getting suspending with manually triggered the workflow.